# Visual Studio setup creation: Conditional installation of a file based on file search fails

Tags: installation

I had created a setup 7.7.0 using Visual Studio 2010. The setup installed all the files correctly. Now I create the setup 7.8.0. The Upgrade Code for both 7.7.0 and 7.8.0 is the same and the Product Code is different.

In the Launch Conditions Editor, I have added a search condition FILEEXISTS1 that searches for a file, d.xml, in a particular location on the system. In the File System Editor, I added the condition "NOT FILEEXISTS1" on the d.xml file to evaluate if the file is present and if it is present, to not install d.xml.

My problem is that having this condition removes the d.xml file altogether when 7.8.0 is installed. However, if I just have the search condition FILEEXISTS1 that searches for the file, but does not evaluate it (meaning I do not have the condition property NOT FILEEXISTS1 evaluated on d.xml), then the file is not overwritten.

I am confused by this behavior. Am I missing something here?
Does anyone know why this happens? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A major upgrade automatically uninstalls the old version before installing your new one. This means that the old file is removed and a new one is installed.

So conditioning your new file is not a good approach for preserving the original one.

To determine if the new file is installed, Windows Installer uses the [file versioning rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the [component key path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Here is an article with more details: http://setupanddeployment.com/windows-installer-bugs/missing-files-upgrade

A solution for preserving your old file is to create a backup before the upgrade starts and restore that backup after the upgrade finishes. This can be done through [custom actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Perhaps this will help: http://setupanddeployment.com/installer-concepts/preserve-data-install

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The link says that the condition NOT FILEEXISTS1 prevents the new file from being installed and the RemoveExistingProducts removes the existing file and hence the file is removed which is exactly what happens to us. However, if I do not give the file search condition NOT FILEEXISTS1 on my d.xml file, but still have my search condition then the file is not overwritten in the subsequent install. Is RemoveExistingProducts not done in this case for the file ?

Comment: It's hard to tell without investigating the upgrade log. Try creating one and post it somewhere so we can take a look: http://setupanddeployment.com/debugging/msi-log/